# Variable 'xxx' was never mutated, consider changing to 'let'

Tags: swift, option-type

**Updated to xcode7-beta** I run across a new kind of warning. Here is my code

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var attributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    if let layoutInfo = self.layoutInfo {
        attributes?.append(layoutInfo)
    }
    return attributes
}
```

the warning message is 
`Variable 'attributes' was never mutated, consider changing to 'let' constant`

Why does xcode say `Variable 'attributes' was never mutated`?

**Question Update**

the warning is gone when I change my code to this

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var attributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    if let layoutInfo = self.layoutInfo {
        attributes!.append(layoutInfo)
    }
    return attributes
}
```

so forced unwrapping can take it away. But it might not be a good thing right?

Comment: did you try to change to let? It still compiles?

Comment: Hi @Icaro I need to append my layoutInfo so I really need a var

Comment: So it must be a bug in the compiler!

Comment: I'm inclined to think that in this specific case this might be a bug. With the iOS 9 SDK a lot of Cocoa Touch classes have been audited to support Objective-C generics, and the compiler may be confusing some of these newly typed NSArrays with typed Swift arrays. Using var here offers the suggestion to use let, but using let produces an error.

Comment: Looks like a bug. With `attributes!.append(layoutInfo)` instead of `attributes?.append(layoutInfo)` the warning disappears :)

Comment: @MartinR Yes you are right

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They talked about this in the WWDC videos and the release notes.

It has always been the case that you get much, much better performance (faster speed, smaller space) if you use `let` instead of `var` whenever you can. This tells the compiler that this thing is a *constant*, not a variable, and that fact allows the compiler to optimize all kinds of things away.

But the compiler can't do that unless you *do* use `let` whenever you can. It won't change a `var` to a `let` *for* you.

Therefore, in Swift 2, the compiler does a smarter analysis at build time and warns you if you are using `var` where you could have used `let`. Eventually this feature will work properly, at which point you should take the compiler's advice!

Comment: *" if you have plans to add more code where you will in fact change this value"* – that code is already present.

Comment: @MartinR It's only a beta, so evidently the smartness of the compiler is not all there yet. I didn't say it was working perfectly, I'm just describing what the warning is supposed to be for! :)

Comment: If that were true, why all programming languages use variables (not constants) primarily? Even the Assembly language has mutable registers!

Comment: Do you have a link regarding performance optimizations? It certainly is safer, and I could imagine some optimizations, but the amount of memory is still the same whether you modify it or not.

Answer (score 12):

This has been driving me crazy too. Whenever I have a class and I change member properties, it still tells me that I should make the variable a constant. For instance:

```
class X { 
    var name = ""
}

var xInstance = X()
xInstance.name = "my name"
```

Near as I can figure, the compiler is correct. xInstance is a constant. It is assigned the pointer to the X instance during its initialization and is never assigned another value. So xInstance is constant. The class that it points to is not constant. 
This is more obvious in a language like C or C++ but when you realize that all class instances are really pointers to heap backed classes, this makes sense.

For those who understand C++

xInstance is equivalent to:

```
X *xInstance
```

making it a let instead means that it changes to:

```
X * const xInstance
```

I think most people would intuitively think that the swift declaration would be equivalent to

```
X const * xInstance
```

Comment: This makes a huge amount of sense to an old fossil like me. let gives you a constant pointer to a variable object. Here's an interesting wrinkle though... if you are declaring a struct rather than a class, the entire struct will be immutable / constant.

Comment: Greg, thanks for this answer! @EliBurke, would you happen to know why this would occur? I'm confused as to how I can rationalise this difference?

Comment: If you are asking about my "interesting wrinkle" comment-- structs are value types (like Ints or Bools). Think of the fields of a struct in the same way as the bytes of an Int. Search on "swift struct vs class" and there are plenty more answers about this.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring a constant with `let`, you ensure that it can never be changed. This is good for making sure that you don't accidentally change it later, and it (in theory) can help the optimizer generate faster code.

If you declare a variable with `var`, and you don't intend to change it or call mutating methods on it, using `let` instead helps you enforce that contract.

Answer (score 1):

You have created that object as var object but value of that object not changing then after better to make it let. That's it.

As per Apple Developer Guidelines, create var object if value of that object is going to change else create let variable. Best practise

Answer (score 1):

Your code implies that `attributes` could be mutated if `self.layoutInfo` is non nil

Perhaps the warning is saying that no path leads to `self.layoutInfo` being non nil and hence attributes has no need of being a var.

Examine what conditions if any can lead to `self.layoutInfo` having data

Answer (score 0):

### Why this warning?

Because in Swift "`let`" means "value is constant" and allows compiler to do some optimizations, hence "`let`" is faster than "`var`",
And since "Swift 2", the compiler warns if we use "`var`" wherever it detects that we could use "`let`" instead.

### Class vs Struct

However, in Swift the "`class`" is a reference-type (just like in `Java`), meaning the "value" is just "a reference and/or pointer to actual data".

Even if we use "`let`" with "class", the "data" pointed is never constant (and is always mutable).
So, if changing the "data" is a big thing and should not happen unnoticed, consider using `struct`.

In Swift "`struct`" is a value-type, and unless it's defined with "`var`" (or "`inout`" in "`func`" parameters), any mutation to the "data" it holds should cause compile error.

> Basically same as `const` keyword available in `C` and `C++` languages, but in `C++` we don't need to migrate from "`class`" to a complete different type, jsut to have mutability sensitive class.
>
> That's a plus for C++, but it fades to nothing, once we see the other C++ overcomplications.