# var and let definition change over swift and swift2. Is var definition changed in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

When I use `var alert = UIAlertView()`
in **swift** it does not give any warning, but when I use the same `var alert = UIAlertView()` in **swift 2** it gives me the following warning:

> Variable 'alert' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

I ended up changing it to:  `let alert = UIAlertView()`

**Question:**
Have the definitions changed over language version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Var` and `Let` in Swift 1.2 and 2.0 work exactly the same. `var` is used for a variable and `let` is used for a constant. While they didn't change the function itself they did add some more error handling to help in different categories, for example memory consumption. a `let` uses less memory than a `var` so why use a `var` when you are not changing it's value? PS: You don't **have** to change it. The error is the little yellow triangle and not the red circle one. Your program will compile and work as is if you leave it to `var` instead of `let` **BUT** it would be wiser to change it to `let` and that's why you get this **warning**.

You can also have a look here for a more in depth description of the following: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746532/variable-xxx-was-never-mutated-consider-changing-to-let)

Comment: so in swift (older version) (xcode 6.4) when i am using "var alert = UIAlertView()" it's not showing any warning so its a compiler bugs?

Comment: Not a bug. It's a new feature added with Xcode 7.0 and Swift 2.0.