# Swift 3 Compiler Warning: Variable was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, variables

I get the following warning in declaring my `variables` in Swift 3.

`let` is not an option because the *var guess* and *var correctGuess* need to change during runtime and must be written using `var`.

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Your current code *does not* change these variables, so, as the warning says, you can use `let`. If you add code that changes these variables then this warning will go away.  Note that the lifetime of these variables is an invocation of the function, so while they may have *different values* on a subsequent invocation of the function, this does not count as mutation; new variables will be created each time the function runs, therefore you can use `let` constants

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the reply.
Using `let` did removed the warnings, however my code no longer worked since I need to create a random number `var correct = arc4random_uniform(5)` . 

This was helpful.
_But the compiler can't do that unless you do use let whenever you can. It won't change a var to a let for you._
source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746532/variable-xxx-was-never-mutated-consider-changing-to-let

Comment: Well, since you are assigning the random number when the view controller is instantiated, it won't change unless you assign it a new value somewhere else. This is nothing to do with the use of `let` with the two variables shown.

Comment: @Paulw11 Used `let` all throughout and it worked with no warnings. Thank you!